# Redis : sum aggregation for keys having some regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I am trying to implement a page View Counter in my rails application using Redis following this tutorial -> http://codemy.net/posts/analytics-with-redis-part-3.

In this tutorial keys are getting added like this :

$redis.incr "Stats:#{Date.today.year}:#{Date.today.month}:#{Date.today.day}:post:#{@post.id}:views"

Now, if i want to get total views count for a particular post id, what are the options?

One naive way is to first get all keys:

keys Stats:*:post:1:views
and then iterate on those keys  to get value and add them.

I am pretty sure there would be some Redis way to do this or any other ds to use in this type of usecase. Can someone please help me, I am very much beginner with Redis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the easiest and best way to do something like this in Redis is to keep a dedicated counter for the stat breakdowns you want to track.  So, for example, if you wanted to track today's views and all time views you might have two increments:

```
d = Date.today
$redis.incr "Stats:#{d.year}:#{d.month}:#{d.day}:post:#{@post.id}:views"
$redis.incr "Stats:alltime:post:#{@post.id}:views"
```

Then you simply query the 2nd key to get the alltime aggregate.